# count number of records from table using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 tables customers and orders I am running left join query to get all customers and count how many orders posted for each customer but the problem is when i run left join query if any customers have 0 orders It is not returning that customer

Customers Table

```
id | first_name | last_name | address | agentID | status
```

orders table

```
id | customerID | title | order_total | balance | status`
```

Here is my sql statement

```
SELECT customers.*
    , COUNT(orders.id) AS TotalOrders 
FROM customers LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customerID = customers.id
WHERE customers.agentID = '2'`
```

Comment: can you set up a db fiddle that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: Please share me the link and I will post there sorry i dont have link of the said fiddle

Comment: use https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT

Comment: ok trying to understand this fiddle will send you once done

Comment: unebl to create fiddle sorry

Comment: is there anybody to help me out ??

Comment: With a WHERE that filters on agentID you will not get all customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a `GROUP BY` clause. Example rewritten for example database from db<>fiddle

```
SELECT store.store_id, COUNT(customer.customer_id) AS customers 
FROM store 
LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.store_id = store.store_id
GROUP BY store.store_id
```

Check https://dbfiddle.uk/7KNckO1X